# Have R not exit debugger if error

Tags: r, debugging

When I'm in the debugger (from a `browser` statement for ex.), if I find the code that gives an error, R exits the debugger. But I want to stay in it. How can I do that automatically (e.g. I don't want to manually have to remember to reset option(error) to something when I'm in the debugger.

Comment: That is new to me. In my expereince the debugger never quits unless I press `Q`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Weird, I thought the debugger kept going for me too, but I just checked and it kicks me out like OP describes... `R 3.0.2`

Comment: no it should not, and does not for me. Please give a reproducible example. Are you sure you do not execute empty lines instead ? "Setting option "browserNLdisabled" to TRUE disables the use of an empty line as a synonym for c. If this is done, the user will be re-prompted for input until a valid command or an expression is entered."

Comment: What happens when you run `func <- function() { browser(); stop('foo'); cat('never get here'); }`, then `func()`, then step once with `n`. Do you stay in the debugger? I don't. I'd really like to know how to disable that, since it's "plagued" me for years. Granted, while in the debugger, if I *manually* run code that fails, it does not exit, but that's different.

Comment: R 3.4.1, I do stay in the debugger.

Comment: @dash2 Could you say a bit more about your OS, RStudio version, any RStudio settings?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `options(error = recover)`.  This will exit the debugging session and immediately offer to enter a new one, with variables as they were at the time of the error.

For example,

```
options(error = recover)
myfun <- function(x) x + "a" ; debug(myfun) ; myfun(2)
```

This leads to the following interactive lines:

```
debugging in: myfun(2)
debug: x + "a"
Browse[2]> n
Error in x + "a" (from #1) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: myfun(2)

Selection: 1
Browse[3]> ls()
[1] "x"
Browse[3]> print(x)
[1] 2
Browse[3]>
```

To make this happen automatically, just put the `options(error=recover)` call as a default for the session.

Comment: This works as advertised! It does conflict with a lot of users' advice about how the debugger shouldn't exit the in the first place. Do you know what's the "expected behavior"?

Comment: If I look at the help pages for `debug` and `browser`, I see no mention of what happens if an error is signalled during browsing.  So there is no "expected behaviour".  Certainly normal R behaviour would be to exit back to the top level, but `options(error=...)` settings (like the one I gave) can change that.   In RStudio, there's a menu option for `Debug | On Error`; that doesn't appear to work on my system, but I'm not up to date on RStudio or R versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be due to a misunderstanding about the levels of debug.  If, for example,  you execute `debug(myfunc); myfunc(...)` , and `myfunc` calls some other function, then the called function is *not* in debug mode.   If that function throws an error,  `R` quite properly exits the entire environment.  Imagine if it didn't: what would happen during non-debug mode?

One solution is: after entering `myfunc` in debug mode, and you know what called function throws the error, to execute `debug(that_func)` so you can follow its error path.

Another workaround is to manually enter the offending function call at the debug prompt (instead of hitting RETURN to have the debugger run the next line of your code). In this way, you'll get the error message back but since it was user-called rather than actually executing a line of the code being debug-run, the debugger will not exit.

Please feel free to comment if this is unclear.

Comment: This is not the behavior I'm experiencing. A reproducible example: `myfun <- function(x) x + "a" ; debug(myfun) ; myfun(2)`. As I `n` stepping through the code, the debugger immediately exits after I execute the `x + "a"` line. I'm using RStudio.

Comment: @Heisenberg  I don't understand your comment.  The debugger exited because it finished executing every line of `myfun` .  That's not what the OP is talking about

Comment: I don't think it's true that the debugger exits because it runs out of line. My debugger still exits if there are more lines. This behavior happens in both RStudio and shell R. GIF proof: https://giphy.com/gifs/xT9Igkho0T7MfRGqwU/html5

Comment: @Heisenberg it looks like an Rstudio bug. Try updating you R/Rstudio versions

Comment: Or try running it in plain R (not Rstudio)

Comment: @DavidArenburg The problem persists with latest RStudio (Version 1.1.383) and R (3.4.2). Plain R also doesn't work.